# The path to the file does not work in the .jar (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Locally everything works fine, but when I start the jar, 
**I get an error that it cannot recognize the path.** 
This is what the code looks like:

```
Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("classpath:images/" + image_title.getOriginalFilename()).toURI());
              
Files.copy(image_title.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Error:

```
2021-08-01 00:41:47.174 ERROR 13188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: Are you uploading image?

Comment: You need to check what is null reference here. If file not there then file not found exception should be there.

Comment: @muasif80 That's right

Comment: @muasif80 If I try to select a file that is not already in that folder I get: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [images/img.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist